# When I close an Android App running a CodeIgniter Web Application in the Android Web Browser the CodeIgniter session does not close

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, session, phonegap-build

**Hi, I am building a Mobile App using CodeIgniter and PhoneGap/Cordova.**

My App opens a local static HTML document in the android web browser and then I use window.open to redirect to an external url to the server where my web application is runing. I log in the web application, close the mobile app and when I open it again the sesión on the web application did not close when it should have because in the codeigniter config.php i set the variable

$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;

which should close sessions when closing all Windows of a browser, it works well using any web browser on a pc but doesnt using the android web browser within my mobile App built using phonegap and compiled using phonegap build.

Any help would be very welcome.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005). In addition, your app may be rejected by the App stores. Read the Link.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the php variable $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to distinguish if a url is called from the Mobile App or from the Web Application and based on that load one HTML document or another.